# Can't use string as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: perl

I'm trying to compare two large files and write every line containing the same content with "Mus musculus" into a new file. My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $infile1 = "geneIDs3_MouseToUniProtAccessions.txt";
my $inFH1;
unless (open ($inFH1, "<", $infile1)){
    die join (' ', "can't open", $infile1, "for reading", $!);
}
my @list1 = <$inFH1>;
shift @list1;
close $inFH1;

my @list1_new;
for ($a = 0; $a < scalar @list1; $a++){
    if ($list1[$a] =~ /(.*Mus musculus.*)/){
        push @list1_new, $1;
    }
}

my $infile2 = "affymetrixIDs_MouseToUniProtAccessions.txt";
my $inFH2;
unless (open ($inFH2, "<", $infile2)){
    die join (' ', "can't open", $infile2, "for reading", $!);
}
my @list2 = <$inFH2>;
shift @list2;
close $inFH2;

my @list2_new;
for ($a = 0; $a < scalar @list2; $a++){
    if ($list2[$a] =~ /(.*Mus musculus.*)/){
        push @list2_new, $1;
    }
}

my @list = ("");
for ($a = 0; $a < scalar @list1_new; $a++){
    for ($b = 0; $b < scalar @list2_new; $b++){
        if ($list1_new[$a] eq $list2_new[$b]){
            push @list, $list1_new[$a];
        }
    }
}

unless (open (@list, ">", "match_1.txt")){
    die join (' ', "can't write the common interest");
}
```

After running, perl gives me an error stated `Can't use string ("1") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at match_for_part_III_9.pl line 47.`

Does anyone know how to fix it? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which line is line 47?  I'm not in the mood for squint-counting at my screen.

Comment: `unless (open (@list, ">", "match_1.txt")){`

Comment: For one, you are trying to use the scalar representation of `@list` as your filehandle for the last `open` call. That's wrong.

Comment: I think what you want is `open my $fh, '>', 'match_1.txt'; print $fh @list;`. This is going to be a facepalm moment. :)

Comment: You might also want to post that code on [codereview.se], there are a few things that can be improved to make your code way more readable. If you're interested, that is. Some of them include using `$a` and `$b`, which are global variables reserved for `sort`. Also, your `@list` will always contain a blank line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use the scalar representation of `@list` as your filehandle to open `match_1.txt` for writing in line 47.

> ```
> #             VVVV
> unless (open (@list, ">", "match_1.txt")){
>     die join (' ', "can't write the common interest");
> }
> ```

Instead, you want to create a new file handle, and `print` your `@list` to that handle.

```
open my $fh, '>', 'match_1.txt' or die "Can't write the common interest: $!";
print $fh @list; # will join on $\ implicitly
close $fh;
```

Comment: OK, it seems to be the problem. However after I tried to modify the last part of code to `my $inFH;
@list1_new = <$inFH>;
unless (open ($inFH, ">", "match_1.txt")){
 die join (' ', "can't write the common interest");
}`, it gives me a new error `Use of uninitialized value $inFH in <HANDLE> at match_for_part_III_9.pl line 54.
readline() on unopened filehandle at match_for_part_III_9.pl line 54.`

Comment: @WenjiaZhai why are you reusing a filehandle with a name that's clearly for reading? And why are you reading from a filehandle that was opened for writing? Line 54 is not included in your question, so I can only guess.

Comment: It's a new file handle. I want to use this filehandle for writing but I don't know how to put values into a filehandle.

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved. I didn't realize it is the solution.